# Reasons for EGARCH(1,1) producing higher/worse AIC/BIC than GARCH(1,1)

Tags: aic, garch, bic, arch

I am using the log returns of 3 different stock indices.

Two of them show improvements in AIC/BIC critereon when I fit EGARCH(1,1) in comparison to GARCH(1,1). One does not. Assuming that estimation procedures are identical, what could be a practical or theoretical reason that EGARCH is not an improvement for index 3?

**Index 1**

GARCH (1,1) AIC -211083.23
GARCH (1,1) BIC -211388.52

EGARCH(1,1) AIC **-21426.9**
EGARCH(1,1) BIC **-21315.3**

**Index 2**

GARCH (1,1) AIC -21748.75
GARCH (1,1) BIC -21893.34

EGARCH(1,1) AIC **-22580.85**
EGARCH(1,1) BIC **-22457.69**

**Index 3**

GARCH (1,1) AIC **-22189.38**
GARCH (1,1) BIC **-22174.91**

EGARCH(1,1) AIC -21335.42
EGARCH(1,1) BIC -21606.81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretical reason: if the true model is GARCH(1,1), then given a large enough sample, AIC and BIC will prefer GARCH(1,1) to EGARCH(1,1) (or to any other model). Of course, we need not assume that the true model is strictly GARCH(1,1); it is enough to assume that the true model is more similar to GARCH(1,1) than to EGARCH(1,1).

In practice that could mean that the third stock index is generated by a different process than the first two indices, where the difference is not only in model coefficients but also in the functional form.

Comment: I estimated EGARCH(2,1) for the third index and found it to be superior to the GARCH(1,1). What can we conclude from this/our data?